# Run a script if an error in syslog appears

Tags: linux, debian, rsyslog

Is it possible to run a shell script if a specified string is found in rsyslog 5.8.11? 
I couldn't find any examples so I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$Template MyAlert,":msg"
:msg, contains, "ThisIsAnErrorMessage" ~
*.* ^/script.sh;MyAlert
```

Can someone give me an idea?

Comment: How often do you want to check for an error? How big is the logfile?

Comment: Well, as I understood this system it should execute that script everytime the error occurs. Or am I wrong? log file is about 1M